# Animating perpetual motion with a forward moving line (TikZ/beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations, animate

I am trying to create an animation that gives a visual notion of a perpetual forward motion in time. What I would like to create is:

1. An arrow starts moving towards the right of the *x* axis.
2. Below the *x* axis, the time tick values are shown, lets say from 1 to 10.
3. The arrow grows in length from 1 to 10.
4. After it reaches the length of 10 in its *x* coordinate, the labels (*x* axis) keep on incrementing, but the arrow length doesn't need to change (thus remain 10 units).

I am new to TikZ/`beamer`, I tried various approaches, but could not get much close to the desired goal. What I have currently is something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\begin{frame}{Progress in Time}
\begin{animateinline}[
 begin={ % header of each frame
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 [line width=1pt]
 \path[clip] (0,-3) rectangle (11,6);
 },
 end={\end{tikzpicture}},autoplay]{3}
 \multiframe{10}{iCount=1+1}{
 \node (s) at (1,0.5) [] [label=below:$\iCount$] {};
 \node (r) at (8,0.5) [] {};
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\sup}{\iCount + 1}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incr}{\iCount/10}
 \node at (3,0.5) [] [label=below:$\sup$] {};
 \path (s) -- (r) node[pos=\incr,coordinate] (p) {};
 \draw[->] (s) -- (p);

 } % end of multiframe
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Code (`animate`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,animate}
\usetheme{Warsaw} \usecolortheme{whale}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Progress in Time}
\begin{animateinline}[
  begin={%
    \tikzpicture[line width=1pt]
    \node[below] at (10,0) {\phantom{00}};
    \coordinate (start) at (0,0) ++ (up:.25cm);
  },
  end=\endtikzpicture,
  autoplay,
  palindrome
] {1}
  \multiframe{20}{iCount=1+1}{
    \draw[->] (start) -- ({ifthenelse(\iCount<10,\iCount,10)},0)
       coordinate (target)
       node[below] {\iCount};
    \foreach \cnt[evaluate={\Pos={\cnt/\iCount}}] in {0,...,\the\numexpr\iCount-1\relax}{
      \path (start) -- (target) node[below, pos=\Pos] (@) {\cnt};
      \draw (@.north) + (up:2pt) -- + (down:2pt);
    }
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Code (`convert`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw} \usecolortheme{whale}
\begin{document}
\foreach \iCount in {1,...,20,19,18,...,2}{%
\begin{frame}{Progress in Time}
\tikzpicture[line width=1pt]
  \node[below] at (10,0) {\phantom{00}};
  \coordinate (start) at (0,0) ++ (up:.25cm);
  \draw[->] (start) -- ({ifthenelse(\iCount<10,\iCount,10)},0)
     coordinate (target)
     node[below] {\iCount};
  \foreach \cnt[evaluate={\Pos={\cnt/\iCount}}] in {0,...,\the\numexpr\iCount-1\relax}{
    \path (start) -- (target) node[below, pos=\Pos] (@) {\cnt};
    \draw (@.north) + (up:2pt) -- + (down:2pt);
  }
\endtikzpicture
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel. That is the perfect solution. Thanks a lot!